# How to use Java 12's Microbenchmark Suite?

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh, java-12

According to [JEP 230: Microbenchmark Suite](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/230), there exists a microbenchmark suite built-in to Java 12. The JEP explains that it's basically JMH, but without needing to explicitly depend on it using Maven/Gradle. However, it doesn't specify how to go about accessing the classes/annotations that belong to the suite to perform a benchmark.

My questions are:

- Is there a specific Java module that I need to require in my `module-info.java` to be able to use this suite?
- What package(s) are the classes/annotations of this suite located in?
- Are there any major differences between this suite and JMH?

Comment: As far as I understood, this is not a tool for you to create application benchmarks. This is for creating benchmarks for the JDK code, which are not even included in a regular JDK build. As stated on the linked page, “*The benchmark suite is not required for regular developer JDK builds; it will be a separate build target.*”

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your interpretation is incorrect. The JEP says:

> Add a basic suite of microbenchmarks to the **JDK source code**, and make it easy for developers to run existing microbenchmarks and create new ones.

i.e. this is not necessarily something that makes it into a JDK distribution, just something that is added to the source code repository to make it easier to run benchmarks on JDK code. Though, to be fair, the fact that it's [listed](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/12/) as one of the JDK 12 'features' seems a tad misleading.

The benchmarks can be run by using the OpenJDK build system. Once you have cloned the OpenJDK source code from `https://github.com/openjdk/jdk` (or another repository that includes the JEP), you can run benchmarks e.g. by using:

```
make test TEST="micro:java.lang.reflect"
```

Benchmarks are located in the `\test\micro\` directory. See also the documentation: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/doc/testing.md#microbenchmarks

Also, this requires you to specify JMH and it's dependencies when generating a build configuration:

```
bash configure --with-jmh="/path/to/jmh/jars"
```

The specified path should point to a directory containing the JMH jars. Required jars are: [commons-math3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.6.1), [jmh-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.jmh/jmh-core/1.21), [jmh-generator-annprocess](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.jmh/jmh-generator-annprocess/1.21), and [jopt-simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jopt-simple/jopt-simple/5.0.4).

Comment: It’s not the first time that something is listed as feature of a new Java version that is merely an internal implementation detail, like “code cleanup” or “finally get all the source code repositories into one”, etc. Likewise, the list does not make a difference between general Java features and features of the reference implementation aka HotSpot/OpenJDK.

Comment: @Holger Yeah, the things listed on the JDK 12 page seem to be a dump of the JEPs with fixVersion 12 from JBS: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8209093?jql=issuetype%20%3D%20JEP%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%20%2212%22